# Using session storage for acces tokens

Tags: javascript, cordova, security

Im working on a cordova app at the moment but im a bit worried about security

Im using an home made api to get the data in to my app but basicly anyone can send requests to that and so acces my data. At first i had a token generator in the app based on deviceID and a static salt key, but since cordova apps are VERY easy to reverse engineer i had to come up with something else.

My idea was generate temporairy tokens from the server and put that in the session storage, but i dont know if that is safe either.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

mate, where to store is not a problem, how to scure your request is the thing you need think about, you need send user a temp guid after they logged in, the guid can be a sessionId in cookie which will expire in a certain time, it's quite common to use a http only cookie for authentication, so the user can not modify their temp cookie themselves.

PS: you never can stop people reverse engineer your app, you should looking for a architect which secure the transferring sensitive data. Also, you can do a encryption on the session Id  as well if you want.

check this: http://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/